# Delphi Equivalent To VB "Space"

Tags: string, delphi

Visual Basic "Space" Function returns a string consisting of the specified number of spaces.

Visual Basic Example:

```
Property Get Sections() As String
Dim sBuf As String
Dim iSize As String
Dim iRetCode As Integer
    sBuf = Space$(8192)
    iSize = Len(sBuf)
    iRetCode = GetPrivateProfileString(0&, 0&, m_sDefault, sBuf, iSize, m_sPath)
    If (iSize > 0) Then
        Sections = Left$(sBuf, iRetCode)
    Else
        Sections = ""
    End If
End Property
```

What is the Delphi equivalent for "Space"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the direct question, the closest equivalent is [`StringOfChar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StringOfChar):

```
sBuf := StringOfChar(' ', 8192);
```

---

Although if you were translating the code in the question to Delphi you would not fill the string with spaces. The VB code is not actually interested in what the string contains when it allocates it, it just uses `Space$` as a simple way to allocate a string of certain length. The spaces are overwritten by the string returned from the API call.

In Delphi you would allocate a string of length 8192 by writing:

```
SetLength(sBuf, 8192);
```

And indeed in Delphi you would use `TIniFile` to read from an INI file. So if you are actually trying to translate the code in the question, I suggest that you don't do so and instead use Delphi's built-in libraries.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought so.  Not sure about the Visual Basic's IniFile capabilities.  Just need a few more eyes on this.  Thanks again.

Comment: TInifile (the one that wraps the Win API) has a 2048 character limit on (/in) ReadString. We specifically created a TCustomIniFile descendant to work around this limit.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Wouldn't it just have been easier to use `TMemIniFile`?

Comment: We do that too, but TMemIniFile use suffers from writes being in memory and not being written to file unless you explicitely tell it to do so. Something most people that are used to TIniFile tend to forget. Also using TMemIniFile means the entire file is read and written. Not nice when you do frequent writes and want immediate saving.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `StringOfChar`:

```
// set txt to 80 spaces
txt := StringOfChar(' ', 80);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could use this function ..

```
 function FastDupeCharA(Chr:Char;n:integer):string;assembler;
asm
 PUSH EBX
 PUSH ESI
 PUSH EDI
 XOR EBX,EBX

 MOV BL,AL
 MOV EDI,ECX
 MOV EAX,ECX
 MOV ESI,EDX
 XOR ECX,ECX
 CALL SYSTEM.@LSTRSETLENGTH
 MOV EDI,[EDI]

 MOV BH,BL  {Fill EBX  with BL (Char)}
 PUSH BX
 SHL EBX,16
 POP BX

 CMP ESI,8
 JLE @DupCarefully
 MOVD MM0,EBX
 PUNPCKLWD MM0, MM0

 @NextFill:
 MOVQ [EDI], MM0  {Fill 8 Char}
 ADD EDI,8
 SUB ESI,8
 CMP ESI,8
 JGE @NextFill
 EMMS
 TEST ESI,ESI
 JNE @DupCarefully
 JMP @FIN

 @DupCarefully:
 {If n or esi is smal than 8 }
 MOV [EDI],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+1],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+2],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+3],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+4],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+5],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+6],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+7],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN
 MOV [EDI+8],BL
 DEC ESI
 JE @FIN

 @FIN:
 MOV EAX,[EDI]
 POP EDI
 POP ESI
 POP EBX
 end;
```